# Trying to Change a Reference Variable

Tags: java, image, reference, resources, game-engine

I have a game engine that tries to load resources efficiently by storing Images in a HashMap. When I want to load an image for a Sprite object, I simply say Sprite.image = LOAD_IMAGE(imageName);

Now I'm making a map editor for this game. I'd like to be able to rotate certain tiles, such a tile of a house to face different directions through Java Image manipulation. I have that working; however, the error arises in the way I set the image to the new rotated Image. I say Sprite.image = rotateImage(Sprite.image); This leads to ALL TILES of the same type to have the same new rotate image.

What can I implement into my game so that each Sprite can be rotated and not affect the other Sprite's Images? I would still like to also keep my HashMap if possible, as I think it would really increase the efficiency of my game.

This is how I implement my rotation:

```
terrain.terrainImage = ImageManipulator.mirror(currentTile.terrain.terrainImage, false);
```

This is my "ImageBank":
public HashMap images = new HashMap(30);

```
public synchronized Image getImage(String imgName) {
    // Check if the HashMap images already has the specified image
            // by checking for the image name.
    if (imgExists(imgName)) {
        // Sprite already loaded.
        return hm.get(imgName);
    } else {
        // Sprite hasn't been loaded yet.
        Image img;
        img = loadImage(imgName);
        if (img == null) {
            // An error occured, couldn't load sprite.
            return null;
        } // else move on

        // save the loaded sprite (and now transparent) into the hashmap
        hm.put(imgName, img);
        // and then return the sprite
        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code. How are you storing the sprites at the lowest level? What's the implementation of your load and rotate methods?

Comment: I highly suspect it has nothing to do with "Java's pass by reference style" when ... Java isn't pass by reference. I'm guessing you have exactly one tile.

Comment: Haha, terribly sorry, got mixed up between reference and value.

Answer (score 0):

Either you store for each tile if and by which angle it is rotated (and than rotate it each time you draw it) or you store rotated copies on the image.

I recommend storing rotated versions.

Comment: I've tried storing rotate versions. I made a new image, set the Image equal to "mirror" function above, stored the new image, and then set the terrain's image to the new image. Every other tile was changed however.